# Having trouble accessing variables of JSON response in JAvascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, object

I am calling an API using an AJAX call and then processing the response ready for output. THe only problem is, I cannot seem to access what looks like an array inside the response object and I can't for the life of me figure out why. It would seem just a basic thing to do but when I try and call the particular response value directly and log it in the console, it shows undefined.

Here is my response object:

```
{
    format: "small",
    _links: {
        self: {
            href: "http://www-*******.net/v1/trading/exchange"
        }
},
    _embedded: {
        exchangeData: [  
                server: {
                     time: "10:01",
                     date: "08.12.2014"
                },
                expert: {
                quantity: "48,069",
                country: {
                ..................
```

Now, the variable I want to be accessing is the 'quantity' value of the 'expert' object. I thought this would be the way to get it:

```
response._embedded.exchangeData['expert'].quantity
```

IS this correct? It is not returning any value and I thought this is usually such a straightforward thing to do.
THanks

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. Even if you ignore missing quotes (which are fine in JS but not in JSON), there are still errors. Use http://jsonlint.com/ and fix the errors.

Comment: exchangeData is array, you can access items of array by it's index. But the problem is that it not well formed array, you need to reformat it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSON brackets `[]` are for arrays.  For example, you could have `["a", "b", "c"]`, which you access with a numeric offset, such as `response[1]`.

Curly braces `{}` are for objects (similar to hash tables in other languages), such as `{"first": "a", "second": "b", "third": "c"}`, which you access by referencing the property by name, such as `response.first`.

The notation is pretty simple, [see the specification here](http://www.json.org/).

In this case, you should fix the JSON source to read:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "exchangeData": { 
            "server": {
                 "time": "10:01",
                 "date": "08.12.2014"
            },
            "expert": {
                "quantity": "48,069",
                "country": {
```

Note that the character after exchangeData is now a curly brace, not a regular bracket.  Then, you access it with:

```
response._embedded.exchangeData.expert.quantity
```